# MySQL NOT IN query giving wrong results

Tags: mysql

```
select count(*) from call_log
where relation_id in (14,15)
and date(from_unixtime(created_time/1000)) = '2018-12-10';
```

Result : 1600

```
select count(*) from call_log
where relation_id in (14,15)
and date(from_unixtime(created_time/1000)) = '2018-12-10'
and id not in (NULL);
```

Result : 0

```
select count(*) from call_log
where relation_id in (14,15)
and date(from_unixtime(created_time/1000)) = '2018-12-10'
and id in (NULL);
```

Result : 0

Ideally, sum of results for query 2 an 3 should be equal to result of query 1. Or there is some issue while comparing with NULL.

Answer (score 4):

`IN()` can not handle `NULL` values. Instead use `IS`

```
and id is not NULL
```

or

```
and id is NULL
```